How to Optimize DynamoDB Data Model. Please advise
I'm currently working on a DynamoDB data model for an application that manages workout plans - to try get more knowledge of DynamoDB.
Each plan has multiple workouts, and each workout has multiple exercises. Here's my current table structure:



PK
SK
Other Attributes




PLAN
PLAN#001
PlanTitle, PlanDescription, etc.


PLAN
PLAN#002
PlanTitle, PlanDescription, etc.


PLAN
PLAN#001#WORKOUT#001
WorkoutName, WorkoutDetails, etc.


PLAN
PLAN#001#WORKOUT#002
WorkoutName, WorkoutDetails, etc.


PLAN
PLAN#002#WORKOUT#001
WorkoutName, WorkoutDetails, etc.


PLAN
PLAN#001#WORKOUT#001#EXERCISE#001
ExerciseName, MuscleGroup, etc.


PLAN
PLAN#001#WORKOUT#001#EXERCISE#002
ExerciseName, MuscleGroup, etc.



Issue:
The current structure uses the same partition key (PK = PLAN) for all items, regardless of whether they are a plan, workout, or exercise. The structure doesn’t clearly reflect the relationships between plans, workouts, and exercises - I can't distinguish them to make the proper requests to retrieve them.
Desired Access Patterns:

Retrieve all plans with their metadata (e.g., PlanTitle, PlanDescription).
Retrieve all workouts for a specific plan.
Retrieve all exercises for a specific workout.

I'm new to DyanamoDB structuring and any help would be greatly appreciated!
Attempted to restructure the PKs and SKs

Take the leading part of your sort key and make it your partition key.



PK
SK
Other Attributes




PLAN#001
PLAN#001
PlanTitle, PlanDescription, etc.


PLAN#001
WORKOUT#001
WorkoutName, WorkoutDetails, etc.


PLAN#001
WORKOUT#002
WorkoutName, WorkoutDetails, etc.


PLAN#001
WORKOUT#001#EXERCISE#001
ExerciseName, MuscleGroup, etc.


PLAN#001
WORKOUT#001#EXERCISE#002
ExerciseName, MuscleGroup, etc.



Retrieve all plans with their metadata (e.g., PlanTitle, PlanDescription).

Serve this from a global secondary index where the partiton key is plan title, meaning the index will only contain the root plan info, and you can scan to get all plans.

Retrieve all workouts for a specific plan.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE PK = PLAN#001

Retrieve all exercises for a specific workout

SELECT * FROM table WHERE PK = PLAN#001 AND SK begins_with WORKOUT#001

